# delete empty columns in a huge file

Tags: python, linux, sed, awk, pandas

What is a the fastest way to delete empty columns in a file. An example file is given below.

I used python 'pandas' package, but it is taking too much time (After ~10 min I didnot get the answer, and so quit as I have to do this for many files) to load my 2 GB file.

```
df = read_table(inFileName, sep="\t")
df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all') #remove columns

aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
1   a       c   
2   s       d   
3   d           
    f       d   
4   g       d   
5   h       e
```

I do not know in advance which fields are empty. 
I am using 0.9.1 version of 'pandas'

> > > pkg_resources.get_distribution("pandas").version
> > >       '0.9.1'

Comment: Do you know what columns are empty, or do you want the program to figure that out?

Comment: Try something lower level - C + Linux's `open`, `write` and `read`.

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?  Significant speed increases were made in 10.0 http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#file-parsing-new-features

Comment: a 2GB file should not take very long. Define "too long" please. Also, it might help if you posted your code so that we can try to point out inefficient code

Comment: @Danny pl see the edit.

Comment: `ccc` and `eee` are empty, right? are `aaa` and `ddd` considered empty too?

Comment: So it reads in ok (the `read_table` line), but the dropna is slow?

Comment: @AndyHayden, Updated 'pandas' to version 0.10. but not helping. I started loading the file 25 min ago, it is still processing. I feel loading itself is the problem

Comment: @Zelazny7, update helped a little bit for smaller files (I tested on 500 MB). For my 2 GB file it is still the same. I am waiting for this file to load since 25 min without any luck

Comment: Are you doing this in ipython/a terminal? i.e. line-by-line? (and it is the first line which it's stuck on?) Have you had a look at how much memory your system is using?

Comment: I am testing these codes in terminal. My activity monitor in Mac is showing something like" free 19 mb, wired 1.3 gb, active 9.7 gb, inactive 4.8 gb, used 15.9 gb'

Comment: I think Pandas is unable to load 2 gb file. I memory tested this and compared with readline() on command line interface. The memory usage goes from 4 gd to 6 gb. Then I used read_table() function, the memory usage goes from 4 gb to 16 gb and even after that could not load the file. Since I have only 16 gb, I started getting page faults. I concluded not to use pandas' for large files

Comment: Have you tried using [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)?

Comment: Pandas can work with very large files.  You just have to iterate over the file using for example `chunker = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=50000)`.  You can then concatenate the files using `pd.concat([chunk for chunk in chunker])`.

Comment: If this was a database file to be loaded, I wouldn't care that some columns are empty. Do you think that cutting out the extra columns will make the file load significantly faster? (I don't). Although, per  your comment, that the software can't load a 2GB file, that sounds very possible. That the software doesn't report an error indicates it's 0.10 version level. Maybe you should file a bug report with the developers. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess you found out that you didn't really want to delete those columns after all. But here is how you could do it in `gawk`.

```
awk -F "\t" 'ARGIND==1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n[i]+=$i!=""
}ARGIND==2{
    if(!ok){for(i in n)if(!n[i])delete n[i];asorti(n);ok=1}
    for(i in n)printf("%s\t",$n[i]);printf("\n")
}' input.txt{,} > output.txt
```

This works by making two passes through the file. The first counts the number of entries in each column, while the second only prints those columns that had at least one hit. For your example file (assuming tab-separated columns, and removing the aaa bbb etc. header, I get the result

```
1   a   c   
2   s   d   
3   d       
    f   d   
4   g   d   
5   h   e
```

But yuck, 2 GB text files. Don't you have a more suitable binary format to store that in?